# Python-Oracle Error Handling multiple steps

Tags: python

I have 4 functions-1,2,3,4 in my python module, each function does a insert stmt and I want the subsequent function to be executed only if the prior function ended successfully..

How would I do this?

code.py

```
 def main():
      func1()
      func2()
      func3()
      func4()

 def func1():
     try:
        insert into table1
     catch:
        database.error as e

 def func2():
     try:
        insert into table2
     catch:
        database.error as e
```

Comment: Are asking if each function can't return a value?  I suppose you can take the try catch out of the individual functions and let the exception prevent further execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the subsequent functions to be executed only if the prior function ended successfully, then call them in sequence in one `try .. catch` block.

```
try:
  function1()
  function2()
  function3()
  function4()
except database.error as e:
  print 'Database error occured'
```

and don't catch exceptions in the functions.

Comment: Thanks..but when can I commit, I want to commit only if all the functions is successfull.

Comment: So put the commit just after `function4` in the `try` block.

Comment: In the except, How can I determine the function that has failed?

Comment: You can do something like this: before `try` create a variable, let's call it `stage` and assign 0 to it (`stage = 0`). Update the variable after each call to your functions, after call to `function1` do `stage = 1`, after call to `function2` do `stage = 2` and so on. If, for example, `function3` fails and exception is thrown, you'll be able to check the `stage` variable in the except block and see that only first 2 functions run OK, cause `stage == 2`.